# Issue in Reading Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection

Tags: c#-4.0

I have an app.config xml like this

```
 <ProcessConfiguration>
    <Entry>
      <Type>type1</Type>
      <folder>folder1</folder>
      <fileName>filename1</fileName>
      <Command arguments="arg1">command1</Command>
      <history>history1</history>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
      <Type>type2</Type>
      <folder>folder2</folder>
      <fileName>filename2</fileName>
      <Command arguments="arg2">command2</Command>
      <history>history2</history>
    </Entry>   
  </ProcessConfiguration>
```

And I have added this in config sections as well

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="ProcessConfiguration" type="Assembly.namespace, Assemblyname"   
 requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
  </configSections>
```

But I am not able to implement the configsection as I am not sure how to handle the ConfigurationElementCollection and ConfigurationElement here. Can anybody help me out on this??

Comment: I tried the way given on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx link. But my XML is very different from what is shown there.

Comment: Thanks Maheep. I am new here so was not able to format properly.

Answer (score 0):

For each entry in app.config you will have to use **add** tag.

Something like this:

```
<ProcessConfiguration>
    <ConfigurationElementCollectionName> <!-- In your custom config section class -->
        <add>
            <Type>type1</Type>
            <folder>folder1</folder>
            <fileName>filename1</fileName>
            <Command arguments="arg1">command1</Command>
            <history>history1</history>
        </add>
    </ConfigurationElementCollectionName>
</ProcessConfiguration>
```

Comment: We cant read the XML as it is which I have provided? Are there some limitations for that?

Comment: Around 2-3 months ago I also tried the same thing after reading the same MSDN article and that did not work. After looking at various SO questions at that time, I found that for a collection of settings we will need the add tag.

Comment: hmm ok. If possible can you provide me an idea on how to implement the ConfigurationSection,ConfigurationElementCollection and ConfigurationElement Classes for above XML whih you have shown. I am totally confused while trying this. Please help